# Dropbox automatically fill javascript

Tags: javascript, html, append, dropbox

```
 $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");
```

the following function filling option select, how could I execute this function when the display select

```
liste_id_Valeur(e.target.id);
```

Comment: I do not understand a single word what you are asking... and I guess I'm not the only one.

Comment: Please give us some more details, or code. This is not a real question. We can't help you with the iformation you provided.

Comment: liste_id_Valeur(e.target.id); //this function is used to fill select

how can I call when viewing a select element??

Comment: i use 
`
$("select").live('click',function(e)
{
liste_id_Valeur(e.target.id);
}
);
`

Comment: Perhaps `$('select').change(...)`

Comment: $('select').change(...) : not work :(

Comment: $('select').change( function (e) { liste_id_Valeur(e.target.id); }); did not work?

Comment: How does dropbox fit into this question? Also what does the trigger('create') do?

Answer (score 0):

In your select tag, you can do the following

```
<select id="my_select" onchange="changeFunc();">
</select>
```

Or if you want to pass the id when it changes, just pass the id as an argument

```
<select id="my_select" onchange="changeFunc('my_select');">
</select>
```

Then you can call the function **liste_id_Valeur** you have inside **changeFunc**

Comment: $('#header-right-container').append(''+nom_champ+'<select id='+Id+' onchange="liste_id_Valeur(\'' + Id + '\');" ><option value=0> </option></select> ').trigger("create");

Does not work :(

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors you can read from a console?